# Error : The approval process references the workflow action FieldUpdate #### which doesn't exist for the **** object

Tags: workflow, custom-object, approval-process, field-update, package.xml

While deploying the Approval Process through Change Sets, I am facing this error at line 15(in img) : The approval process references the workflow action FieldUpdate Status_to_Complete, which doesn't exist for the Opportunity_Support_Request__c object.

According to this error, it is saying about the workflow action but I haven't used any workflow action.
I saw few posts to create/update package.xml file but I think my object is not from any managed package. Also, I didn't get how to create package.xml file in the Salesforce sandbox org. What I found is the Approval Process xml file, but not sure how to edit it.

Any suggestion/advice is helpful !
Thanks...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Got an appropriate answer for this and I think it will work form everyone. In Change Sets, I had included apex class, triggers, custom fields, email templates etc. whatever required EXCEPT WORKFLOW FIELD UPDATES,WORKFLOW EMAIL ALERTS etc. that I created in Approval Process. So, I added them all along with the approval process in Change Sets.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like the OP did not include the required files in the change set and seems to have figured out the problem.

Comment: you should self-answer this one

Comment: @Deep What do you mean by "didn't find a proper solution". Your first comment is the correct solution for this deployment error.